# How can I customize the Lion login screen to remove the vignette effect?

Tags: macos, login, customization

Just upgraded to Lion, but the new login screen needs some colour. I found someone online who posted the address of the image that's in the background, so I went and replaced that.

Only, after doing that, I realized that there's an additional overlay being drawn that adds a vignette effect by brightening the center of the screen.

Does anyone know of a way to remove this?

Comment: Where's the link to the post that tells how to replace the original image?

Comment: @Moshe This link: http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=13006515&postcount=9 ??

Comment: I agree, this is very annoying. Been trying to find the source of this 'gradient' effect for a long while, yet no avail. I have followed the instructions on changing the wallpaper but there still appears to be a and overlay on the wallpaper. I have found where to remove other elements such as the apple logo and avatar etc. but STILL cannot see that effect anywhere.

Comment: how do you remove the logo and avatar? Link?

Comment: Hrm... Digging around in that folder didn't yield much. Could it be a Quartz effect that can't be removed?

Comment: Logo is /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Versions/A/Resources

Comment: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1190045

Comment: It is a pity that none of the comment links are about removing the undesired "vignette effect" at the login window. Hope that setting a bounty gives an answer for removing the vignette effect.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the effect is actually something that's drawn programmatically. I dug around for a while and I can't seem to find it anywhere. My suggestion: Open your image in a graphics editor and modify it to account for the shadow.

Comment: This is a workaround and not an answer because when creating a background image that negates the vignette effect, there is still an image applied. Which also needs to be transferred over the line when using remote desktop. And the asker would like to have a completely black screen: it is impossible to create an image with more black than black to compensate for the effect of the vignette effect.

Comment: @ProBackup True, but if it's being drawn programmatically, then the answer is that you can't have a totally black login screen. Although, the compensation is to lighten the image, and black on black would be black.

Comment: The vignette effect is a spotlight. Therefore the only compensation is to darken. But black can't be made darken then black.

Comment: Looks like it's is a coded effect as Moshe says, not just a simple image overlay. I made a transparent PNG that can be layered on top of another image to cancel out the light and shadow effect fairly convincingly (though not mathematically exact), but the result is necessarily a lower contrast image; the darkest black will be a dark grey, and the brightest white will be a light grey. http://cl.ly/HzsC ...I tested it layered on a screenshot of the login screen, but I haven't actually tried it live.