# How do I change the login screen background in Lion?

Tags: macos, login-screen

I want to change the login screen background in Lion, but I can't seem to figure out how. I've followed [instructions](http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/02/change-login-screen-wallpaper-os-x-lion/) for changing it, but even after restarting, the changes don't show up. I've also tried [Loginox](http://www.loginox.branox.com/), but that didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use "Deeper". You can download the beta version which works with Lion 10.7.4 (assuming your using Lion of course).

You can download it [here](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/joel.barriere/dl/107/Deeper.dmg). (Initiates download)

Authors website:

> Deeper is a personalization utility for Mac OS X which allows you to
>   enable and disable the hidden functions of the Finder, Dock,
>   QuickTime, Safari, iTunes, Login window, Spotlight, and many of
>   Apple’s applications...

Example of option to modify login screen:

[image]

You can also revert your login screen back to it's default settings if you so choose.

Comment: Deeper worked! Thanks so much. Now to get rid of [the vignette effect](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18451/7833).

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Loginox](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/39250/loginox) which does basically the same things as Deeper.

Considering how drastically Apple changed the loginwindow and its various properties, you might also want to [leave some feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html) requesting that they make it easier to manage (ie, setting a 'property of' type banner message shouldn't require a 3rd-party utility).

Comment: "I've also tried Loginox, but that didn't work either"

Comment: Really?  I used it yesterday on a brand new 10.7.3 install and it worked fine.  Had you tried any other methods to change the loginbackground?  If you try using Loginox or Deeper to reset the background to default, restart, then try to change it again what happens?

Comment: I'm on 10.7.4 (I don't know if that makes a difference). I've tried the other method, which I linked to in my question. I have not tried using Loginox to reset the background, but I will try it and let you know.

Comment: When Apple updated to 10.7.4 they changed something that caused software that typically worked to make changes to the login screen no longer work. I just had this issue with Deeper and emailed the developer. He resolved the issue so Deeper would work with the updates to OS X Lion 10.7.4.

Comment: After posting my comment I also noticed that after using Deeper, Loginox would no longer work.